# CPF memory error in ML 8

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I have a custom CPF, that when a document gets stored, it extracts the text and also done annotation.. for about 1000 documents it works fine, then it gives error for next couple of documents , and after that again it works fine.. the files for which it gives error is random.. Following is the error msg

```
2016-02-22 14:49:31.580 Debug: Forest::insert: content-repo-content-001-1 XDMP-INMMLISTFULL: In-memory list storage full; list: table=79%, wordsused=76%, wordsfree=0%, overhead=24%; tree: table=3%, wordsused=87%, wordsfree=13%, overhead=0%
2016-02-22 14:49:31.580 Info: Saving /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/content-repo-content-001-1/00000070
2016-02-22 14:49:31.595 Debug: InMemoryStand /var/opt/MarkLogic/Forests/content-repo-content-001-1/00000071, disk=10MB, memory=436MB, list=341MB, tree=85MB, rangeIndex=11MB, reverseIndex=11MB, tripleIndex=44MB
2016-02-22 14:49:31.805 Info: content-repo: File Name : S-2010-000029581.pdf
2016-02-22 14:49:31.805 Info: content-repo: Content Type : application/pdf
2016-02-22 14:49:31.805 Info: content-repo: id : 11c565782e85d213ef00bed474bf25ad84d465d3
2016-02-22 14:49:32.023 Debug: Retrying SVCProcess::run 1 because SVC-PROCESSRUN: Process run error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
2016-02-22 14:49:32.204 Debug: Retrying SVCProcess::run 2 because SVC-PROCESSRUN: Process run error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
2016-02-22 14:49:32.437 Debug: Retrying SVCProcess::run 3 because SVC-PROCESSRUN: Process run error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
2016-02-22 14:49:32.765 Debug: Retrying SVCProcess::run 4 because SVC-PROCESSRUN: Process run error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
2016-02-22 14:49:33.298 Debug: Retrying SVCProcess::run 5 because SVC-PROCESSRUN: Process run error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
2016-02-22 14:49:34.224 Debug: Retrying SVCProcess::run 6 because SVC-PROCESSRUN: Process run error: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

In marklogic is there a way to clear temporary allocated memory after each CPF action ??

Thanks

**UPDATE**

I was thinking that this is due to memory error and CPF not releasing resources.. so what I did was in my CPF I do the xdmp:spawn-function to do my annotations, thinking that it will be queued up in the Task queue.. But when I do that I get the following exception, even for a single document

> 2016-02-23 16:25:50.498 Info: TaskServer: 
>   2016-02-23 16:25:50.498 Info: TaskServer:   XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES
>   2016-02-23 16:25:50.498 Info: TaskServer:   
>   2016-02-23 16:25:50.498 Info: TaskServer:   1.0-ml
>   2016-02-23 16:25:50.498 Info: TaskServer:   Conflicting updates
>   2016-02-23 16:25:50.498 Info: TaskServer:   XDMP-CONFLICTINGUPDATES: xdmp:document-insert("/documents/BioEln/de249f6f43d7e6ecdb1a809769852542a944087c.pdf/a...",

Following is my code, my CPF calls this function `repo-lib:transformDoc`

```
(:~
 : Function that transoforms the documents
 :)
declare function repo-lib:transformDoc($uri as xs:string){
    if(repo-lib:isEmpty($uri)) then ()
    else
        (: annotations :)
        let $_ :=  xdmp:spawn-function(function(){repo-lib:loadAnnotatedDoc($uri), xdmp:commit()},
               <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
                   <transaction-mode>update</transaction-mode>
               </options>)
       (:let $_ := repo-lib:loadAnnotatedDoc($uri) :)
        return ()
};

(:~
 : This function annotates the document..
 :)
declare function repo-lib:loadAnnotatedDoc($uri as xs:string) as xs:string
{
    (: for now we are using termite but we can use anything maybe smartlogic :)
    repo-lib:loadTermiteAnnotations($uri)
};

declare private function repo-lib:deleteDocument($uri as xs:string?)
{
    if($uri) then
        if(fn:exists (fn:doc ($uri))) then
            xdmp:document-delete($uri)
        else ()
    else ()
};

(:~
 : Load termite annotations
 :)
declare function repo-lib:loadTermiteAnnotations($uri as xs:string) as xs:string
{
    if(repo-lib:isEmpty($uri)) then ""
    else
        if(crfslib:uri-exists($uri)) then
            let $newDocUri  := $uri||"/annotatedText/"
            let $id := xdmp:document-properties($uri)//id/text() (:check if the document has id :)
            let $id  := if($id) then $id
                        else xdmp:sha1($newDocUri) (:if not generate a unique id:)
            let $app  := xdmp:document-properties($uri)//context/text() (:check if the document has id :)

            (: This will take care of updates, so delete the old copy :)
            let $annotatedTexLocation := xdmp:document-properties($uri)//annotatedText-location/text()
            let $_ := repo-lib:deleteDocument($annotatedTexLocation)

            let $newDocUri := $newDocUri || $id || ".xml"
            return
                try{
                    let $boundary := "------WebKitFormBoundaryIbhnU2N5CiXjjSU0"
                    let $termite := "http://10.239.12.38:8080/termite"
                    let $dictionary := "ADVENT,ADVENTMED,ANAT,BIOCHEM,BIOPROC,CELLLINE,CHEMBLDRUG,CHEMSTR,COMPANY,COMPOUNDS,DRUG,DRUGFIND, DRUGTYP,INDICATION,PROTYP,LABCHEM,GENE,GENEONT,MOA,ORPHAN,CHEMO,DEVICE,SPECIES"

                    (: Let us get the extracted text :)
                    let $text := xdmp:quote(xdmp:document-filter(fn:doc($uri)))

                    (:Call termite to do the annotations :)
                    let $termite_output := lib-multipart-post:multipart-post($termite, $boundary, (<data name="text">{$text}</data>,
                                                                                            <data name="format">any.xml</data>,
                                                                                            <data name="output">xml</data>,
                                                                                             <data name="entities">{$dictionary}</data>))
                    let $transformed_annotations :=
                        xdmp:xslt-eval(
                            <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
                                <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
                                <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

                                <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
                                    <xsl:copy>
                                        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
                                    </xsl:copy>
                                </xsl:template>
                                <!-- Apply all child nodes; don't copy the element itself -->
                                <xsl:template match="ResponseBlock|ResponsePayload">
                                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                                </xsl:template>
                                <!-- Drop elements -->
                                <xsl:template match="DictSynList|MatchedSynonyms|TaxonomyList|Taxonomy|MetaHeader|Source|HitLocations|HitLocationString|Exact|TotalSyns|HitCount|Score|NonAmbigSyns|Fragments|KeyValuePairs|Mappings"/>

                            </xsl:stylesheet>,$termite_output[2]
                        )

                    (: delete the document if exisists :)
                    let $_ := repo-lib:deleteDocument($newDocUri)
                    (: let us add and annotatons :)
                    let $_ := xdmp:document-insert($newDocUri, $transformed_annotations,(xdmp:default-permissions()), ("annotated", "termite", $app))
                    (: let us add the propertier :)
                    let $_ := xdmp:document-add-properties($newDocUri, (<document-parent-location>{$uri}</document-parent-location>,
                                                                        <context>{$app}</context>,
                                                                        <id>{$id}</id>))
                    let $log := xdmp:log("Dne inserting the document")


                    (: let $_ := xdmp:commit() :)
                    (: add the extracgted text as well :)
                    (:) let $_ := xdmp:document-add-properties($uri, (<annotatedText-location>{$newDocUri}</annotatedText-location>)) :)
                    return $newDocUri
                }catch($ex) {
                    let $log := xdmp:log("ERROR !!!!!")
                    let $log := xdmp:log($ex)
                    return ""
                }
        else
            let $log := xdmp:log("ERRRO!!!! - Document does not exisist yet")
            return ""
};
```

Comment: Can you share relevant piece of code, the exact version of ML you are running, and whether it happens consistently with the same files, or with different ones each time?

Comment: grtjn, I updated my question

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to do a little too much in one CPF action. CPF is intended as a state engine, where a document slowly moves through various states with multiple actions contributing small changes.

For this, CPF will keep track of state and progress using document properties in cpf: namespace. I think that is why you are getting update conflicts. Don't use spawn, and either split the work into multiple actions, or consider using a simple trigger to do all at once.

HTH!